What are Aeron io.aeron.cluster.service.Cluster#cancelTimer guarantees?
I read the docs at https://aeron.io/docs/aeron-cluster/cluster-timers/#best-practices and there is a following statement that left me confused - "When canceling timers - even with unique correlation IDs - you may receive the timer firing event if the cancellation was requested very close to expiry. Ensure that your business logic can deal with this scenario.".
Does that mean that if the call to io.aeron.cluster.service.Cluster#cancelTimer returns true I might still receive io.aeron.cluster.service.ClusteredService#onTimerEvent for the same correlation id?
Javadoc comment doesn't provide this information. Are the docs up to date and I still have to consider such a scenario?
Thanks.
